# android studio doesn't run my app on iso emulator

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, android-studio, dart

I don't know if this problem is coming due to update mac os to macOS Monterey, but suddenly android studio doesn't run my app on ios, on Xcode working fine, even i created new project but still the same issue, I can see ios device in the devices list, but when I select it, android studio doesn't keep it selected!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps

Open Xcode

```
  Xcode -> Preference -> Locations -> Command Line Tools
```

Select Xcode your_xcode_version

Now go to Android studio and run flutter doctor

Hope this one resolve your issue.